# Update line in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How update line in odoo 9?

Source:

```
@api.multi
def my_func(self):
    for line  in self.test_line_ids:
        #print(line.name)
        print(line.create_date)
        if (line.create_date == "2017-01-25 10:50:56"):
            self.write({'create_date': '2017-01-11 10:50:56'})
            print("YES")
        else:
            print("NO")
```

I'm try above example, in console print YES but row is not updated in database!

Comment: Are you sure? Check on the database using sql. Because the dates are rendered differently on Odoo depending on the user's timezone.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I'm try other field etc. quantity but again not update.

Comment: How do you call this method? Also please fix your indentation. `@api.multi` should be in the same level as `def my_func(self)`

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas <button string="MY FUNC" class="oe_highlight" type="object" name="my_func"/>

Comment: have you tried direct assignment with `self.create_date = '2017-01-11 10:50:56'`?

Comment: @danidee not working....

Comment: @user_odoo can you put `self.env.cr.commit()` immediately after the `write` statement. My guess is that something else happens that we don't know that prevents the changes from committing to the database.

Comment: @danidee  Not update again https://postimg.org/image/dm2lg6yqv/